# Qual a diferença dessas duas selectors?

Tags: html, css, css3

Queria saber a diferença desses dois modos:

```css
primeiro {
width: 50px;
float: left;
background-color: blue;
height: 50px;
padding: 7px;
}

.primeiro {
width: 50px;
float: left;
background-color: red;
height: 50px;
padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<primeiro> </primeiro>
<div class="primeiro"></div>
```

Comment: O primeiro é uma tag e o segundo uma classe.

Comment: A diferença é só a forma como você selecionou o elemento.

Comment: Posso fazer um site todo em tag então?

Comment: "Pode", não quer dizer que você deva...

Comment: Sim, mas deve tomar cuidado com a semântica

Comment: Entendi, pessoal. Vou dar uma pesquisada e uma aprofundada nisso. Muito obrigado a todos.

Comment: Você tem que ver também qual o contexto desta tag **<primeiro></primeiro>**. Se estiver utilizando um framework **JS** como Angular ou Vue, por exemplo, esta tag indica um **componente**.

Comment: e se vc tiver duas tags com mesmo nome, mas quer uma a esquerda e outra a direita coo vai fazer? O primeira opção que vc colocou é como se fosse um seletor global para todos os elementos de mesmo nome, pode ser bom ou ruim...